# Закрытие\открытие файла для записи при нескольких потоках

Tags: c++, windows

**Задача**: Имеется много потоков (допустим, 50), в которых вызывается функция записи в файл данных (файл для записи один). Как сделать так, чтобы потоки друг другу не мешали, и при этом имелась возможность просматривать файл через проводник?

Т.е. как реализовать потокобезопасную запись в файл, если он после каждой записи в него закрывается?

Comment: очень похоже, что Вы изобретаете логгер.

Comment: Правильный вариант - взять готовый. Велосипедный вариант - либо использовать мютексы. Есть ещё много вариантов.

Comment: Если это не лаба, берите log4cxx, и не изобретайте велосипед. Если это лаба, пишите её сами.

Comment: я когда то брал http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-lightweight-logger-for-c/240147505?pgno=1 и доводил ручками для своей задачи. log4cxx вроде также хорош, но я его не использовал, не могу сказать, насколько он удобен.

Comment: Как вариант: потоки пишут не напрямую в файл, а в очередь (потокобезопасную). Отдельный поток логгера выгребает данные из этой очереди и пишет в файл. Сам файл должен быть расшарен на чтение, чтобы его можно было просматривать другим программам.

Comment: Вы бы уточнили, как именно открываете файлы. Судя по упомянутому Проводнику, код под Windows. Возможно, используется [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Смотрите параметр `dwShareMode` - задайте `FILE_SHARE_READ`.

Comment: В \*nix можно открывать файл с флагом `O_APPEND` и каждую запись делать одним `write`. Вывод из разных потоков не перемешается. Кстати, между write файл можно и не закрывать (открыть его в одной функции в `static int logfd = ...` и всюду писать в этот logfd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря наводке @Alexander Petrov из комментариев к вопросу, получился такой результат, который лично меня вполне устраивает по функциональности. 
Ниже приведу пример, вдруг кому понадобится что-то похожее.

**Описание:** *Класс логгера создавался для выдачи в разные файлы какой-либо информации из разных классов используемых в проекте. Поэтому открывается несколько файлов (для удобства перед названием файла еще пишется дата). Экземпляр класса крутится в отдельном потоке.*

Файл `"Logger.h"`:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

extern std::string PathEXE; // где хранится файл

class Logger
{
public:
    Logger(){ std::cout << "\nLog class created. "+PathEXE; OpenLogFiles(); }// открывает файлы.
    void AddToLog(unsigned type, std::string text); // функция, вызываемая извне, для добавления в буффер, соответствующий желаемому файлу
    void Run();// функция, проверяющая постоянно буфферы на наличие данных
private:
    //method
    void OpenLogFiles();
    void output(std::string text, int i);// функция, печатающая в файл
    std::string pop(int i, int j);// функция, выбирающая что печатать

    //data
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> buffer; // вектор буфферов. Размер - кол-во файлов
    std::vector<HANDLE> file; // хэндлеры файлов
    std::vector<DWORD> filesize; // позиции в файлах

    std::mutex  mutex_; //мютекс

};
```

Файл `"Logger.cpp"`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"

void Logger::OpenLogFiles()
{
    using namespace boost;
    gregorian::date TODAY = gregorian::day_clock::local_day();
    std::string date = to_string(TODAY.day().as_number()) + "-" + to_string(TODAY.month().as_number()) + "-" + to_string(TODAY.year()) + "_";
    std::string tempPath = PathEXE + date;

    std::vector<std::string> path;
    path.push_back(tempPath + "LOGS_1.txt");
    path.push_back(tempPath + "LOGS_2.txt");
    path.push_back(tempPath + "LOGS_3.txt");
    path.push_back(tempPath + "LOGS_4.txt");
    path.push_back(tempPath + "LOGS_5.txt");
    path.push_back(tempPath + "LOGS_6.txt");
    path.push_back(tempPath + "LOGS_0.txt");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i)
    {
        file.push_back(CreateFileA(
            path[i].c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)
            ); // открываем файл с флагом shared_reading
        if (file[i] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // проверка на правильность
        {
            printf("ERROR %x \n", GetLastError());
            std::cout << "\nRELOAD NEEDED. LOG ERROR";//messagebox
        }
        filesize.push_back(0); // заполняем вектор позиций
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * t;
        time(&rawtime);
        t = localtime(&rawtime);
        std::string time = "";
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        time += to_string(t->tm_year + 1900) + "." + to_string(t->tm_mon + 1) + "." + to_string(t->tm_mday) + "/" + to_string(t->tm_hour) + ":" + to_string(t->tm_min) + ":" + to_string(t->tm_sec) + "/" + to_string(t1.time_since_epoch().count() % 1000);

        output("Logs created on: "+time, i);// сразу пишем в файл, когда создан
        std::vector<std::string> buf;//создаем буффер
        buffer.push_back(buf);
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Logger::Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));//для уменьшения загрузки ЦП
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < buffer.size(); ++i)
        {
            int size = buffer[i].size();
            if (size>0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
                {
                    output(pop(i, k), i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Logger::output(std::string text, int i)
{
    WriteFile(file[i], (text).c_str(), (text).size(), &filesize[i], NULL);// пишем в файл
    filesize[i] += (text).size();// сдвигаем указатель
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
std::string Logger::pop(int i, int j)
{
    std::string text;
    text = buffer[i][j]; // читаем начало буффера
    mutex_.lock();
    buffer[i].erase(buffer[i].begin());// elfkztv yfxfkj ,eaathf
    mutex_.unlock();
    text += " s=" + boost::to_string(buffer[i].size()); // добавляем информацию, сколько еще в буффере (у меня максимальный размер был 1 через час работы)
    return text;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Logger::AddToLog(unsigned type, std::string text)
{
    if (buffer.size() < type){ std::cout << "size!"; return; } // проверка на ошибку размера
    mutex_.lock();
    buffer[type].push_back(text);// добавляем в конец буффера
    mutex_.unlock();
}
```

Файл `"main.cpp"`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"
Logger;
std::string PathEXE = "C:\\Projects\\tests\\Release\\"; // задаем путь для файлов
auto logqqq=Logger();// создаем экземпляр класса
void Runner()
{
    logqqq.Run();
}
void helper(std::string text, int i, int timee)
{
    while (true)
    {
        logqqq.AddToLog(i, "\n|text here|\n");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(timee));
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "\nstart";
    std::thread my_thread(&Runner);// запускаем логгер

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));// ждем просто так
//запуски потоков, кидающих что-то в буффер:
//параметр 1 - текст(сейчас не активен), параметр 2 - файл, параметр 3 - частота "вброса" в миллисекундах.
    std::thread my1(&helper, "\ntext1", 0, 1);
    std::thread my2(&helper, "\ntext2", 1, 2);
    std::thread my3(&helper, "\ntext3", 2, 3);
    std::thread my4(&helper, "\ntext4", 3, 4);
    std::thread my5(&helper, "\ntext5", 4, 5);
    std::thread my6(&helper, "\ntext6", 5, 6);
    std::thread my7(&helper, "\ntext7", 6, 7);

    cout << "\nall threads started!";

    my1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Может не максимально оптимально, но в скорости работы проблем не заметил. Да и в объеме затрачиваемой памяти тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Для потокобезопасной записи в файл можно использовать объекты синхронизации — мьютексы и события, которые в каждый момент времени могут предоставить доступ к файлу только одному потоку. То есть каждый поток перед записью в файл проверяет состояние объекта синхронизации и, если он свободен, занимает его и производит запись файл, а затем освобождает. Если же он занят, то встает в очередь и засыпает пока этот объект не освободится. Но может и не засыпать а выполнять другую полезную работу. Для создания объектов синхронизации есть функции WinAPI `CreateEvent`, `CreateMutex` и `SetEvent`. Для ожидания объекта — `Select` и `WaitForSingleObjects`.